# Using the passport package with npm can the req.user object be changed from the client side?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I am curious as to whether it is possible for a user to alter the req.user object from the client-side with the npm package passport? Let me know if you have any insight. Is it a security issue, I am convinced that it comes from session ids I just need this to be confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

req.body object would be removed when the user deletes their cookies or overwritten when the user logs in again.

But there is no way modify or alter the authorized user information from the client-side if you implement it properly